# Unable to use cmdkey and net use to a Azure file share on Windows 10

Tags: azure-storage, net-use

I'm trying to follow the [instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#mount-the-file-share) on how to create a persisted connection to an Azure Storage File Share. However from my Windows 10 machine I cannot get the `cmdkey` / `net use` combination to work:

```
C:\>cmdkey /add:myaccountname.file.core.windows.net /user:myaccountname /pass:myaccountkey

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.

C:\>net use \\myaccountname.file.core.windows.net\mysharename
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

However if I provide the username and password in a single `net use` command it works correctly:

```
C:\>net use z: \\myaccountname.file.core.windows.net\mysharename /u:myaccountname myaccountkey
The command completed successfully.
```

So it doesn't look like a firewall issue.

Any ideas? Is there another port that needs to be open to allow the `cmdkey` scenario to work?

Answer (score -1):

Error 53 usually means that port 445 is blocked. Check the firewall on your computer, and if you are in a corporate environment, ask your corporate IT guys if they are blocking it. Many common ISP's block that port as well. For example, I know it doesn't work on Comcast but I've heard Time Warner Cable does not block it.

Comment: But when I specify the username and password explicitly (rather than rely on cmdkey's saved credentials) it does work - doesn't that mean the firewall is okay?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Looking at your example more closely, I notice that you are missing the drive letter from the net use command in your first example -- the one without the credentials. Can you put * or Z: in there and see if that fixes it?